# Pref angular-ui's timepicker output with a readable string

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my line of code for the timepicker along with some text:

```
<timepicker ng-model="mytime" hour-step=1 minute-step=1 show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
```

I would like to include the text "The current time is ", but when I do that, it doesn't put everything on one line; I've tried using `form-inline` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to your time picker and to the other div you want on the same line :

```
 <div class="comment">current time is : </div><timepicker ng-model="mytime" hour-step=1 minute-step=1 show-meridian="ismeridian" class="timepicker"></timepicker>
```

then add a `display: inline` to these classes in your css :

```
.comment {
     display:inline;
 }

 .timepicker {
     display:inline;
 }
```

Comment: No... that didn't make it in-line (copied your code exactly).

Comment: After little search, I'm afraid that is a know issue of ng-angular. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1012
You could try the hack proposed on this thread.